# Django: how to view raw sql response upon a query

Tags: sql, django

In Django if I want to see the raw sql in debug mode I can check using in django shell:

```
from django.db import connections
User.objects.all()
print(connections['default'].queries[-1]['sql'])
```

Similarly can we see the raw response of that sql. In the above case the sql query may return the raw results in csv, tab delimited format. From then django may create the model objects array.

Answer (score 0):

There are better tools to debug SQL queries in Django. The standard tool is to use Django-debug-toolbar, which allows you to view both the SQL query, the result, and the EXPLAIN output, for all queries in a request/response, along with the time needed for each query. The documentation is available at https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: i want to know how to do it without any third party tools

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
str(User.objects.all().query)

# or 

print(User.objects.all().query)

# or 

print(User.objects.all().query.sql_with_params())
```